# Batch file to Remove lines with particular words from CSVs

Tags: windows, csv, file, batch-file

Hi I have a directory with CSVs that contain lines i do not want to process

So far I have a  a working for all files example below which only shows certain columns and copies to new csv

```
  @Echo off
  For %%F in (*.csv) do ( 
      (for /f "delims=" %%A in (%%F) do Call :Split %%A
      ) > "c:\temp\test\%%~nF_New.csv"
  )
  goto :Eof
  :Split
  Echo(%2,%3,%5
```

But I want to use

```
Echo find /V "Not"
```

to only show me lines that dont have the word "Not"

IF i use the find command like below it works for 1 csv .

```
type test.csv | find /V "Not" > new.csv
```

I need to do this on all csvs indirectory.

Any idea how i combine both into 1 batch script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi I worked it with T&E but here it is for others

```
@Echo off
For %%F in (*.csv) do ( 
    type %%F | find /V "Not" > %%F_new.csv 
)
goto :Eof
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in one go (no `call` needed):

```
@Echo off
For %%F in (*.csv) do ( 
  (for /f "tokens=2,3,5" %%A in ('findstr /v "Not" "%%F"') do echo %%A,%%B,%%C
  ) > "c:\temp\test\%%~nF_New.csv"
)
```